# Can a linear transformation of linearly independent vectors be linearly dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

$:ℝ^k→ℝ^j$ and $ v_1, v_2, v_3$ are in $ℝ^k$ such that the image of the vectors is linearly dependent. If this is true, show that it is possible for $ v_1, v_2, v_3$ to be independent.

I have no idea how to do this. I thought that if the image is dependent the original must also be dependent. Could someone give me an example of this working?

Comment: You can't "create new dimension," but you can "kill the ones you have."

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Consider mapping everything to the zero vector

Comment: Reread your second paragraph. Did you really think what you wrote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:  What is the most trivial linear operator you can think of that kills all the information of the original vectors?

Comment: The identity matrix?

Comment: No, the identity matrix A:  is only defined if the dimensions of the spaces match, and B: Preserves all the information.   You want something that the output doesn't depend at all on the input (That's the most extreme example). . Other examples include where the output only depends on part of the information of the input

Comment: Sorry Alan for these relatively basic questions, but are you referring to a matrix that is just 0s?

Comment: @Despair.-Exactly.  The $0$ matrix (A different one for each $m\times n$ size ignores the input and outputs nothing but $0$ vectors.